# How much Money does Suzie spend on oranges each week?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

This problem is from [Algebra Nation's](https://web.algebranation.com/) ACT prep subject.

Section 10: Statistics and Probability
Topic 6: Comparing data

### The following information is given:

Suzie runs a daycare. Using the charts below, determine how much money Suzie spends on oranges each week.

[image: Chart 1]

[image: Chart 2]

The answer choices are as given:

A. $19.50

B. $19.00

C. $18.75

D. $18.50

### What I tried

This problem was very complicated for me because even though I have the information from the charts, I didn't understand how I could locate how much money Suzie spends on oranges each week when the first chart doesn't tell me how many oranges were sold, when they were sold, and how many of the other fruits were sold. I also don't know what the 1-10 on the side represents.

It is given in the second chart- 1 orange equals $0.75

Assuming that the other fruits aren't involved in the first chart, I tried multiplying the cost for oranges by the number each week ends.

Monday: $0.75×4=$2.96
Tuesday: $0.75×6=$4.50
Wednesday:$0.75×1=$0.75
Thursday: $0.75×6=$4.50
Friday: $0.75×9=$6.75

The next step was to add up all of the solutions.

2.96+4.50+0.75+4.50+6.75= $19.46

19.46 is not one of the answer choices but if you
rounded, it would give us $19.50, which is answer choice A. I still feel like I made a mistake somewhere in the process of solving this problem.

Comment: How could you get an answer not divisible by $5$? Check your arithmetic.

Comment: 4 times 75 cents is $3.00

Comment: You have an arithmetical error in your Monday calculation. You have accidentally multiplied $0.74$ by $4$, rather than $0.75$. ¶ Incidentally, I'm going to edit your tags; this question is neither `analysis` (a technical term) or `calendar-computations`. Please do speak up if you think they're inappropriate, but keep in mind that we're probably more familiar with the tags than you are. :-)

Comment: This is a question about reading tables and plots, it seems. Is there no label to the first plot? I suppose the reader to assume that the vertical scale refers to oranges bought?

Comment: Algebra Nation-related questions seem to all end up wild goose chases.